# graph-tool Euler circuit

Tags: python, graph-tool

I am currently using the `graph-tool` library with Python (3.6) and I just noticed that there is no functionality to extract a Eulerian/Hamiltonian path/circuit. Is there a particular reason for this? I mean I can implement it myself but the point of using this library is to be more efficient than `networkx`. So coding it in Python will be a huge slowdown.

Therefore, what should I do to be as efficient as possible here? And also, why is there no implementation of this in `graph-tool`?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the developers? Perhaps you can be one of the developers? Things like this don't happen by themselves but require people who, like you, can do it themselves, taking the time to work on an open source project and do it for others. Maybe the only answer to the question as to why that functionality is not included is that nobody has yet volunteered their time in that way.